# Jsoup finding if a tag doesn't exist

Tags: image, jsoup, extract

I'm trying to extract the img link of a few car ads.I'm having issues with this because the image is optionally and i really can't check if an ad has  it's image or not. For example let's say that i have the followings ads:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
for (Element searchResult : page2.select(".offer-wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td > a > img")) {
   img = searchResult.attr("src");
   list.get(index).setImgLink(img);

   index++;
}
```

Basically, searchResult will never be  null, it will find only 2 image sources and the second ad will get the image of the third one.How could i handle this and also find a way to check if the second ad has an image?
I've also tried to check if img variable is empty or null but it will return only the source image of the first and third add.

Answer (score 0):

Don't select `a > img`, select only `a` and then check if `img` exists:

```
    Elements searchResults = page2.select(".offer-wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td > a");
    for (Element searchResult : searchResults) {
        Element imgElement = searchResult.select("img").first();
        if (imgElement != null) {
            String imgSrc = imgElement.attr("src");
            list.get(index).setImgLink(imgSrc);
        } else {
            list.get(index).setImgLink(null);
        }
        index++;
    }
```

EDIT: *another way to check for image*

You can observe that links without image on olx have class `nophoto`, so this one also works:

```
    Elements searchResults = page2.select(".offer-wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td > a");
    for (Element searchResult : searchResults) {
        boolean withoutImage = searchResult.hasClass("nophoto");
        if (!withoutImage) {
            String imgSrc = searchResult.select("img").first().attr("src");
            list.get(index).setImgLink(imgSrc);
        } else {
            list.get(index).setImgLink(null);
        }
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've tried the code you suggested but i'm not sure why at the end of the page it throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 42, Size: 42

Comment: It's weird because searchResults variable returns 47 values and on the page there are only 42 ads

Comment: Your `list.get(index)` is reaching for non-existing element. That means you should also take care of the code that fills `list` with values. Also make sure your `index` counter starts from 0.

Comment: At first i populate the list with the title of the ads which works fine(i have 42 instances) but the problem is that i get 47 values from the source of the images

Comment: What i'm trying to say is that the problem comes from the img source:( i'm not really sure why searchResults.size() returns 47 values although there are 42

Comment: Just debug or print everything you have in `list` and every `imgSrc` and compare it with what you see in a browser. Maybe you can use single loop to create `list` instead of creating it first and then setting `imgSrc` in separate loop.